# Given n coins, some of which are heavier, find the number of heavy coins?

Tags: algorithm

Given n coins, some of which are heavier, algorithm for finding the number of heavy coins using O(log^2 n) weighings. Note that all heavy coins have the same weight and all the light ones share the same weight too.

You are given a balance using which you can compare the weights of two disjoint subsets of coins. Note that the balance only indicates which subset is heavier, or whether they have equal weights, and not the absolute weights.

Comment: maybe you could be more specific, in the last sentence you say there have the same weight?

Comment: it means that there are 2 weights at all, "heavy" and "light".

Comment: Do you know the ratio of the weights of each light to each heavy coin? Does a "weighing" show the weight of one particular set of coins, does it show *how much* one set of coins outweighs another, or does it just show that one set of coins outweighs another? Without knowing what information a "weighing" supplies, there is insufficient information to answer this question.

Comment: @MarkBannister  You are given a balance using which you can compare the weights of two disjoint subsets of coins. Note that the balance only indicates which subset is heavier, or whether they have equal weights, and not the absolute weights.

Comment: This looks like either a homework question or interview question. You are likely to get better responses or at this point a reopen if you share your thought process and narrow down to specific question(s).

Comment: @A.Webb actually it's a question that was in past year's final. tomorrow I have Algorithm finals and so I'm looking for this question's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't give away the whole answer, but I'll help you break it down.

1. Find a `O(log(n))` algorithm to find a single heavy coin.
2. Find a `O(log(n))` algorithm to split a set into two sets with equal number of heavy and light counts plus up to two leftovers (for when there are not even amounts of each).
3. Combine algorithms #1 and #2.

Hints:

- Algorithm #1 is independent of algorithm #2.
- `O(log(n))` hints at binary search
- How might you end up with `O(log^2(n))` with two `O(log(n))` algorithms?

Comment: For finding the single heavy one in O(log n) we can divide all coins in half and then choose the heavier half and then divide it again in half and choose the heavier part and so on. is this correct? It is like binary search.

Comment: That the gist, but you also need to be able say something about when the halves have equal weight and how to handle cases where the number of coins is not evenly divisible.

Comment: Do you have something specific in mind? or you gave an algorithm which is just a guess? I am pretty sure it cannot be done better than O(n) with a proof similar to the proof that sorting is Omega(nlogn) problem. In here, you have a subset of coins `{c | c is heavy}` that you need to find. Note however, that the number of possible subsets is `2^n`. Each compare op can 'shrink' your candidates list by half. Thus, the total number of compares need is `Omega(log(2^n))=Omega(n)`.

Comment: @amit We are not asked to find the subset of heavy coins, just its cardinality. If you accept #2 is possible above, then the number of heavy coins is twice the number of heavy coins in one of the equal weight sides (plus any heavies in the one or two leftovers from the split). The other side may be discarded since we aren't trying to actually isolate the heavy coins, and the count of heavy coins in it is the same as in the other side. So each operation cuts the pile in half. There are lg n iterations of a lg n operation (plus lg n to find an initial heavy to compare against leftovers).

Comment: Hint for #2. Split the pile in half. If the halves weigh the same, done, so assume not. Define an order to rotate coins from left to right and right to left. If you did this one pair at a time, there would reach a point where the scales would either balance or tip the other direction. Given your order, do a binary search instead to find when this happens.

Comment: I cannot understand how to do find out the two algorithms !