# Finding all heavy coins in 0(log^2(n))

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

Suppose you are given n coins, some of which are heavy and the others
light. All heavy coins have the same weight, as do all the light coins, and
the weight of a heavy coin is strictly greater than the weight of a light coin.
At least one of the coins is known to be light. You are given a balance,
using which you can weigh a subset of coins against another disjoint subset
of coins. Show how you can determine the number of heavy coins using
O(log2 n) weighings.

Comment: I love homework questions where the poster has not demonstrated any thought

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748903/given-n-coins-some-of-which-are-heavier-find-the-number-of-heavy-coins?rq=1

Comment: It is same as above question but i am unable to solve and come up with necessary algorithms

Comment: ... perhaps do a different course?

Comment: @Aditya-Nambiar it is not exactly the same question. You are asking for something different. Because in this case you are suggesting the possibility of having more than 1 lighter coin.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan The other question is likewise about possibly multiple counterfeits.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this must be a generalization of the problem where you have 8 coins and one of them is light. So you can perform a kind of binary search in order to find the lightest coin using a pair of scales balance. However, it is strange that you are supposed to find several light coins at the same time. In this case, this does not seem to scale with log2 n.

See the example below in order to understand my point.
In the case of 8 coins where one of them is light. You should follow three steps:

Step 1) Divide the sample in two parts and find the lightest part. => 1 weighting. [You got a sample with 4 coins that is lighter]

Step 2) Divide the lightest part of the previos procedure and weight these parts to find the lightest part. => + 1 weighting [You got a sample with 2 coins]

Step 3) Now you have only two coins. You have only to weight them to find the lightest.

Off course, the generalization to a sample of size n is trivial.

The proof that this scales with log2 n follows the binary search proof.

However, if the number of light coins is different from 1, you cannot focus only in the lightest part of the sample. [Disclaimer: Maybe I am wrong, but it is difficult to say that this will scale with log2 n. FOr instance, consider the situation where the number of light coins scales with n (the number of coins)]

Actually, the most beautiful solution to this problem is to find the lightest coin in only two weightings:

Step 1) Divide your sample in 3 parts. The first part has three coins, the second part also has three coins and the last part only 2.

Step 2) Weight the first and the second part. There are three situations:

a) The first part is lighter.

b) The second part is lighter.

c) The first and the second part have the same weight.

If (a or b) wight two of them. If they have the same weight, the other one that was not weighted is the lighter. On the other hand, if they dont have the same weight, one of them is the lighter

if(c) just weight the two coins to find the lighter one.

This can also be generalized, but the generalization is much more complicated.

Comment: See a sketch at the linked duplicate. One way to generalize the question would be to ask to _find_ all the counterfeit coins. But, this question merely asks for a count of all the counterfeit coins, an easier problem.